# How do I set the nameserver (dns) for Ubuntu's initramfs?

Tags: networking, network-manager, initramfs

In `/etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf` are a few configuration options for Ubuntu's initramfs.

Among other things one can set the `IP` and networking `DEVICE` for the inital ram file system there, e.g. `DECCIVE=wlan1` or `IP=192.168.0.10::192.168.0.1:255.255.255.0`.

I have installed dropbear for [unlocking encrypted drives via SSH](https://hamy.io/post/0009/how-to-install-luks-encrypted-ubuntu-18.04.x-server-and-enable-remote-unlocking/) and have the problem, that my server retains the initramfs network configuration even after unlocking and full boot. Since that configuration does not include a DNS, I have to add it manually afterwards and it does not persist.

So how do I configure the nameserver in an initramfs?

---

---

**Things I tried:**

When I set `IFDOWN=*` in `/etc/dropbear-initramfs/config`, the whole network is screwed after boot (not just the nameserver), and I have to do something like:

```
sudo ip link set <device> up
sudo ip a a 192.168.0.10/24 dev <device>
sudo ip r a default via 192.168.0.1
sudo resolvectl dns <device> 192.168.0.1 1.1.1.1
```

Inside the initramfs, a file `/run/net-enp2s0` seems to be responsible for the exact network configuration:

```
# cat /run/net-enp2s0.conf 
DEVICE='enp2s0'
PROTO='none'
IPV4ADDR='192.168.0.10'
IPV4BROADCAST='192.168.0.255'
IPV4NETMASK='255.255.255.0'
IPV4GATEWAY='192.168.0.1'
IPV4DNS0='0.0.0.0'
IPV4DNS1='0.0.0.0'
HOSTNAME=''
DNSDOMAIN=''
NISDOMAIN=''
ROOTSERVER='0.0.0.0'
ROOTPATH=''
filename=''
UPTIME='9'
DHCPLEASETIME='0'
DOMAINSEARCH=''
```

But I have no idea how it gets created and how to change its content. I find the initramfs documentation sadly lacking.

Answer (score 1):

Taken from https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/nfs/nfsroot.txt

> ```
>  ip=<client-ip>:<server-ip>:<gw-ip>:<netmask>:<hostname>:<device>:<autoconf>:
>  <dns0-ip>:<dns1-ip>:<ntp0-ip>
> ```
>
> This parameter tells the kernel how to configure IP addresses of devices and also how to set up the IP routing table. It was originally called nfsaddrs, but now the boot-time IP configuration works independently of NFS, so it was renamed to ip and the old name remained as an alias for compatibility reasons.
>
> If this parameter is missing from the kernel command line, all fields are assumed to be empty, and the defaults mentioned below apply. In general this means that the kernel tries to configure everything using autoconfiguration.
>
> ...

In your case use for enp1s0 as network device (you might need also use eth0):

```
IP="192.168.0.10::192.168.0.1:255.255.255.0::enp1s0:off:<DNS-Server>"
```